# Create instance using ctor injection and ServiceProvider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control

I know there is `IServiceCollection` interface where I can register my services and `IServiceProvider` which can instantiate the services.

How do I instantiate a class, based on specified Type, which uses registered services?

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(ISomeService someService) { }
}

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>()

MyClass instance = CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));

object CreateIntance(Type type)
{
   ???
}
```

For example, how does ASP.NET Core creates controller instances?

I've made naive implementation of the activator but isn't there something like this in .NET Core already?

```
private static object CreateInstance(Type type, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var ctor = type.GetConstructors()
        .Where(c => c.IsPublic)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"No suitable contructor found on type '{type}'");

    var injectionServices = ctor.GetParameters()
        .Select(p => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(p.ParameterType))
        .ToArray();

    return ctor.Invoke(injectionServices);
}
```

}

EDIT: this is my scenario. I've refactored some legacy code that implements this interface.

```
public interface IEventDispatcher
{
    void RegisterHandler(Type handler);
    void Dispatch(DomainEvent @event);
}
```

In the Dispatch method implementation I create instances of the handlers:

```
public class InMemoryBus : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly List<Type> _handlers = new List<Type>();
    private readonly Func<Type, object> activator;

    /// <param name="activator">Used to create instance of message handlers</param>
    public InMemoryBus(Func<Type, object> activator)
    {
        this.activator = activator;
    }

    public void Dispatch(DomainEvent @event)
    {
        Type messageType = message.GetType();
        var openInterface = typeof(IHandleMessages<>);
        var closedInterface = openInterface.MakeGenericType(messageType);

        var handlersToNotify = from h in _handlers
                               where closedInterface.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(h.GetTypeInfo())
                               select h;
        foreach (Type h in _handlersToNotify)
        {
            //this is the tricky part
            var handlerInstance = activator(h);
            closedInterface.GetTypeInfo()
                .GetMethod(nameof(IHandleMessages<T>.Handle))
                .Invoke(handlerInstance, new[] { message });
        }
    }

    public void RegisterHandler(Type type) => _handlers.Add(type);
}
```

Comment: The DI framework will do that for you, just pass in the parameter to your constructors.

Comment: serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>() returns null. In CreateInstance(Type) method I don't know what are the parameters at compile time

Comment: Then we probably need to see some actual code of how you are registering all the services.

Comment: It's all in my question

Comment: Then you are not registering `MyClass`...

Comment: Also, using `GetService<>` is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DavidG: well, I don't think it is antipattern in my scenario, see my edit. Something else smells here more likely, I'm just not sure what. Maybe I should register the handlers into separate servicecollection in RegisterHandler method?

Comment: It's a code smell if you can be injecting these object in the constructor of your class (e.g. the MVC controller.) Using `GetService` means it's much more difficult to test.

Comment: I understand that. But I use GetService only to inject services into my class (Handlers), just like MVC does when instantiating controllers. Test for InMemoryBus are [clean](https://github.com/Liero/vyvojari-sk/blob/dev/tests/CommandStack.Tests/Infrastructure/InMemoryBusTests.cs) and the actual handlers does not call GetService().

Answer (score 26, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756192/45091 is the right way to do things.

> For example, how does ASP.NET Core creates controller instances?

If you don't want to register the services you can use what we refer to as "type activation". There's a type called ActivatorUtilities that has the helper method you want. You call `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, type)` and it will activate that type with the specified service provider.

Comment: is there a way to use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(type, serviceProvider)` with hybrid parameters, some from the container some provided yourself?

Comment: Yes, it has extra arguments

Comment: Is there a way to combine both DI type resolution and parametrized instance activation? If not, I think that might be a useful feature: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69207420/1768303

Answer (score 15):

Given

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(ISomeService someService) { 
        //...
    }
}
```

You need to build the entire object graph so that the provider knows what it can create

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>()
serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyClass>();

IServiceProvider provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

MyClass instance = provider.GetService<MyClass>();
```

When `provider.GetService<MyClass>()` is called the provider will initialize `MyCLass`, resolving all dependencies in the process.

Reference [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: Yes, I know that when I register MyClass and the services I will be able to resolve it. But do I really have to register all possible classes? First off all, MyClass is not a service, so I'm not sure it belogs to ServiceCollection. Second, neither Asp.net core registers controllers into ServiceCollection and yet it creates instances of the controllers

Comment: @Liero, You do not see when it registers controller. does not mean they do not. when you call `AddMvc` it reflects all controllers and adds them to the collection. Source code on Github go check

Comment: @Liero I think you misunderstand what a "service" is in the context of DI here.

Comment: @Liero take a look at an answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36549612/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi: I've checked it actually. `IServiceProvider.GetService<MyController>()` returns **null** even after everything is bootstrapped, e.g during request. Maybe it's registered in another scope

Comment: @Nkosi isn't it dangerous to do that.  For instance if you set some value on the singleton provided on the builder provider, it will not carry over the provider internal to the ASP.NET Core application