# With Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, can I resolve the type and construct an instance while providing extra constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

With `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, can I resolve the type and construct an instance while providing extra constructor parameters, in one go?

What I'd like to do is easy to illustrate by example. Below, in `CreateSomethingWithContext` I need to use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to call a parameterized constructor, but I don't know the concrete type for `ISomething` in advance.

I could use `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService` to resolve the type and create a default instance, but then I couldn't pass `context` parameter.

I could use a [factory version of `AddTransient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__), but that would break the code which already uses `GetRequiredService` to create default instances.

Below, a possible kludge (which I dislike) is to create a redundant default instance of `Something` only to figure out its type and pass it to `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`, along with the `context` parameter.

**Is there a better way of doing this?** To clarify, I have no control over the actual library that implements `ISomething`/`Something`.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace App
{
  public interface ISomething
  {
    void DoSomething() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(DoSomething));    
  }  
  
  public class Something: ISomething
  {
    public Something() =>
      Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} created");

    public Something(object context) =>
      Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name} created with {context}");
  }

  static class Program
  {
    private static IServiceProvider BuildServices() => new ServiceCollection()
      .AddTransient<ISomething, Something>()
      .BuildServiceProvider();

    static ISomething CreateSomething(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
      serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomething>();

    static ISomething CreateSomethingWithContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, object context) 
    {
      // first I need an instance of ISomething, only to learn its concrete type for
      var something = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomething>();
      var type = something.GetType();  
      // now that I have the type, I can use ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance
      var something2 = (ISomething)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
        serviceProvider, type, context);
      return something2;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
      var serviceProvider = BuildServices();
      CreateSomething(serviceProvider);
      CreateSomethingWithContext(serviceProvider, Guid.NewGuid());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to define and register your own factory class for this.

Comment: where does `ISomething` come from, where is it managed and created and what does it contain?

Comment: @qujck it comes from a 3rd party nuget package. It's registered with `AddTransient` as above, and gets instantiated via DI as needed by the consuming code.

Comment: I see - where does `context_param` come from? On the surface I'd suggest that's the item that needs a runtime provider

Comment: have you context_param in a config file? if yes... you can create your own class thet extend Something and implement a new Interface custom. And adding a new DipendencyIncection .AddTransient<iCustomSomething, CustomSomething>( x => { return new CustomSomething("context_param"); })

Comment: @qujck and @Den, `context_param` can be unique for each instance. A good example of what it's like is a file name parameter.

Comment: If it's runtime data it's arguably not a constructor argument as these should be design time dependencies. I would suggest some form of runtime context abstraction that makes the data available. You can't avoid the temporal coupling but it should probably be explicitly managed by a well defined abstraction rather than tucked away in the composition root.

Comment: The current solution: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/239918e05697fb5952865dd19a2ae3aa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I agree with you about not wanting to do this with ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance - although it will work, if ever the constructor's signature changes you'd end up getting a runtime error, and I'm sure a compile time error would be preferable.

Why not [register a completely separate factory](https://espressocoder.com/2018/10/08/injecting-a-factory-service-in-asp-net-core/) for constructing your object with the context - Leave the AddTransient() registration untouched so that all calling code that relies on the default constructor would still work, and use newly created factory where you need to insert your `context`?

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, @IanKemp is suggesting that too. The downside is that only the code I directly control would know how to request and use such a factory.  And I'd probably still use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` inside it, for its dynamic DI resolution of other constructor parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are asking for is something that goes fundamentally against the idea of the dependency inversion principle, which is the basis for dependency injection. So it is unlikely that you will find support for something like this in common dependency injection containers.

To understand this, let’s think about why you are actually registering your concrete implementation `Something` as its interface type `ISomething`. By doing that, you are allowing components to depend *on the abstraction* instead of a concrete type. This reduces coupling as it allows you to easily swap the implementation with something else that satisfies the interface specification.

The idea is that you don’t actually want to know what implementation you get when you depend on `ISomething` as long as it is compatible to the interface. That also means that you do not want to know what dependencies that concrete implementation might have itself. Instead, the dependent component gives up the control to an outside system, usually the DI container, and just expects the system to give you the thing you need.

Now, when comparing this idea with `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`, one might observe that this utility method is actually just syntactic sugar around the service locator pattern, which is usually in direct contrast to dependency injection: Instead of relying on the system to give you whatever you depend on, you can now actively request your dependencies from the container itself. `ActivatorUtiltilies.CreateInstance` just does that while also allowing you to pass values that should not be resolved from the container.

Let’s assume that a method existed that allowed you to do `CreateInstance<ISomething>(additionalValues)`. You are now asking the container to provide you with an implementation for `ISomething` but apparently you know so much about the concrete implementation of that, that you are able to tell what parameters you would want to pass in order to resolve it. And that contradicts what I explained above, that you usually (deliberately) don’t want to know what the concrete implementation is.

---

Instead, I would suggest you to create a proper factory for this, something that is made to *create* that `Something` for you, and offers a properly typed way to add that “context” data:

```
public class SomethingFactory : ISomethingFactory
{
    private readonly SomeDependency _someDependency;
    public SomethingFactory(SomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        _someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public ISomething Create()
        => new Something(_someDependency);

    public ISomething CreateContext(object context)
        => new Something(_someDependency, context);
}
```

That factory is then made for the `Something` implementation, so it is perfectly fine that it knows what kind of parameters it would need to pass to the `Something` constructor, and since it has an abstraction `ISomethingFactory` itself, you are still able to do this properly using dependency injection instead of using the service locator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance method is less than preferred, since it requires a concrete type to be used and unfortunately cannot pass an interface for a type. Which can cause issue when unit testing and setting up Mocks.

A colleague came up with another approach through using Func within your Container Builder, and then your IServiceProvider uses that signature to create the instance.

```cs
// Service Builder
Services.AddScoped<Func<Guid, IFooService>>(
  provider =>
    guid => new FooService(guid, provider.GetService<IBarService>());
```

```cs
// Factory Method
public TService CreateService<TService>(Guid id)
  where TService : IFooService
{
  var creator = _serviceProvider.GetService<Func<Guid, TService>>();
  return creator(id);
}
```