# .NET 6 Dependency Injection override

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I want to inject a specific instance (not wired up by DI) as a parameter to my constructor using Microsoft DI and .NET 6.
In the example below I'd like to have an instance of `MyClass` (called `myClassSpecial`) with the constructor parameters instances of `MyInterface1Impl1` and `MySpecialImpementation`.

*EDIT 1* 
In **Unity** there is `DependencyOverride` so basically I guess that this is what I'm looking for in .NET 6 DI ?

*EDIT 2* 
**NB**: The class `Test` below **does not** have access to the concrete implementations `MyClass`, `MyInterface1Impl1`, `MyInterface1Impl2`, but just the interfaces. The classes are loaded dynamically (I just added the AddSingleton lines in case that anyone wants to run the example)

I appreciate any help !

King regards
Magnus

```c#
// Testprogam
var test = new Test();
test.Show();


// Expected output

MyInterface1Impl1
MyInterface1Impl2
MyInterface1Impl1
MY SPECIAL STUFF
```

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly IMyInterface1 myInterface1;
    private readonly IMyInterface2 myInterface2;
    public MyClass(IMyInterface1 myInterface1, IMyInterface2 myInterface2)
    {
        this.myInterface1 = myInterface1;
        this.myInterface2 = myInterface2;
    }

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myInterface1.GetInformation);
        Console.WriteLine(myInterface2.GetInformation);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private IMyClass myClass;
    private IMyClass myClassSpecial;

    public Test()
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().
            ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
            services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface1, MyInterface1Impl1>();
            services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface2, MyInterface1Impl2>();
        }).Build();                      
        
        myClass = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<IMyClass>(host.Services);


        var mySpecialImpementation = new MySpecialImpementation();
        myClassSpecial = ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<IMyClass>(host.Services /*HOW TO INJECT MY INSTANCE OF mySpecialImpementation*/ );
    }

    internal void Show()
    {
        myClass.ShowInfo();
        myClassSpecial.ShowInfo();
    }
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void ShowInfo();
}

public interface MyBaseInterface
{
    string GetInformation { get; }
}

public interface IMyInterface1 : MyBaseInterface
{
}
public interface IMyInterface2 : MyBaseInterface
{
}

public class MyInterface1Impl1 : IMyInterface1
{
    public string GetInformation => $"{nameof(MyInterface1Impl1)}";
}
public class MyInterface1Impl2 : IMyInterface2
{
    public string GetInformation => $"{nameof(MyInterface1Impl2)}";
}

public class MySpecialImpementation : IMyInterface2
{
    public string GetInformation => "MY SPECIAL STUFF";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles on the same issue, here is what helped me solve the issue  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207420/with-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-can-i-resolve-the-type-and-constr).

First I created this helper class:

```
public class DependencyHelper
{
    public static T CreateService<T>(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, object data)
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        var something = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(typeof(T));
        var type = something.GetType();
        var psuChainDevice = (T)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, type, data);
        return psuChainDevice;
    }

    public static T? GetObjectOfType<T>(object parameters)
    {
        switch (parameters)
        {
            case null: throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameters));
            case object[] arrayItems:
                var resultArrayItem = GetFirstMatchingObject<T>(arrayItems.ToList());
                return resultArrayItem;
            case List<object> listItems:
                var resultListItem = GetFirstMatchingObject<T>(listItems);
                return resultListItem;
            case object oneItem:
                var oneItemList = GetFirstMatchingObject<T>(new List<object> { oneItem });
                return oneItemList;
        }
    }

    private static T? GetFirstMatchingObject<T>(List<object> items)
    {
        var result = items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetType() == typeof(T));
        if (result is null) return default;
        return (T)result;
    }
}
```

and used it like this

```
var psuChainDevice = DependencyHelper.CreateService<IPsuChainDevice>(serviceProvider, someDeviceThatWasCreatedSomewhere);
```

the definition of the class (in this example PSUChainDevice) was done like this

```
    public class PSUChainDevice : IPsuChainDevice
{
  public PSUChainDevice()
  {
  }

  public PSUChainDevice(ISomething1 something1, ISomething2 something2, object deviceParameter)
  {
    var ftdiDevice = DependencyHelper.GetObjectOfType<FTDIDevice>(deviceParameter);
  }
}
```

and finally it was wired up as a transient device

```
        public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
    {
        var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddTransient<IPsuChainDevice, PSUChainDevice>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        return provider;
    }
```